# HTML entities for image, audio and video

Tags: html, entity

I want to have HTML entity codes for image, audio and video icons. I saw this on a site but its not working `&audio;`, `&image;`, `&film;`. Please do anyone have a better clue on these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use too the iframe tag too if you want !

[Iframe Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Answer (score 1):

for audio and video you can use html5

```
<video src="http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg" controls>
  Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
</video>


<audio src="/test/audio.ogg">
  <p>Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.</p>
</audio>
```

this is form MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video